# How to convert CMSampleBufferRef from GPUImageVideoCamera to a UIImage? Getting unwanted results

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, gpuimage, ios7.1

I'm trying to extract frame from a GPUImageVideoCamera's willOutputSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer. However, I either get a crash, or the resulting image is very distorted.

Some background info:

- I'm running this on an iPhone 5 running iOS 7.1

This is the code I'm using for processing each frame:

```
- (void)processColorImageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer {

    @autoreleasepool {
        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

        /*Lock the image buffer*/
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

        /*Get information about the image*/
        uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
//        size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
        size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
        size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

        /*Create a CGImageRef from the CVImageBufferRef*/
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
        CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);

        /*We release some components*/
        CGContextRelease(newContext);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

        /*We relase the CGImageRef*/
        CGImageRelease(newImage);

        if (image) {
            framesTaken++;
            [self imageCaptured: image];
        }

        /*We unlock the  image buffer*/
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
    }
}
```

Any help will be very appreciated!